# How to decrypt password in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
$user = User::where('email',$request['email'],'password', Crypt::decrypt($request['password']))->first();
```

How do I decrypt a password in laravel?

This is the error that I'm getting:

> DecryptException in Encrypter.php line 144: The payload is invalid.

Comment: Unless you have *very* good reasons, passwords should never be encrypted. They should always be hashed with a salt (preferably many times using an algorithm such as bcrypt).

Comment: If you're trying to authenticate a user, use Laravel's built-in functions instead of trying to create your own.

Comment: What is your use case, that is what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why/How are you getting an encrypted password in you `$request`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it makes little sense why you would want/need to do this, given Laravel's authentication library.  However, in an effort to help, I'll make this suggestion:

I'm assuming this code is inside a controller and you're passing the request object.  If so, you're using the request object incorrectly, as it's not a simple array.   To obtain the values, you should be calling the input method of the request object:

```
$value = $request->input('password');
```

Docs are [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests).